# Euler characteristic of an Einstein-Cartan manifold

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

In the Einstien-Cartan theory, the Euler characteristic of the manifold $M$ is given by
$$\chi(M) = \int F_{ab}\wedge\star F^{ab}$$
where $F_{ab} = d\omega_{ab}+(\omega\wedge\omega)_{ab}$, $\star F_{ab} = \epsilon^{abcd}F_{cd}$ and $\omega$ is the spin connection. Now, how does one compte the topology of a manifold using this formula? I have only seen people discussing metric on a manifold and using the metric to compute various properties of the manifold without having to refer to connections on it. How can one discuss a manifold purely based on some connection defined on it without refering to its metric?

Comment: What is an Einstein-Cartan manifold?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Where the tetrad and the spin connection are treated as independent or rather where the connection is not Levi-Civita. It is a physics terminology, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a special case of the [Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem).

My understanding is that Einstein-Cartan gravity is a metric-affine theory rather than a purely affine theory, in that the Riemannian metric $g$ and the connection $\nabla$ are both dynamical variables. The connection is still metric, in that $\nabla g=0$, but the torsion is allowed to vary independently of $g$.

While it doesn't apply to general affine connections, the CGB theorem does apply to all metric connections, and it appears that the integrand $F_{ab}\wedge\star F^{ab}$ is indeed equal to $\operatorname{Pf}(F)$. Your formula seems to differ by a factor of $4\pi^2$, and there is some subtlety if you allow nonorientable spacetimes, but I suspect these minor discrepancies are due to unstated conventions that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: So, how does one compute the Euler characteristic in this case? Do you simply assume some connection and compute it? What if your manifold has some conical singularities how will that show up in the connection ?

Comment: The point, more or less, is that the CGB theorem holds for *any* metric and *any* connection compatible with that metric; the integral depends only on the base manifold. You *can* use it to compute the Euler characteristic of a given manifol by equipping it with an arbitrary metric/connection, but this are other applications. To your second point, the CGB theorem applies to manifolds, which are by definition free of singularities. There may be some generalization which applies to algebraic varieties, but I'm not aware of one.

Comment: So, by a compatible connection you mean that the metric $g$ must satisfy $\nabla g = 0$ ?

Comment: @user44690 Yes. "$\nabla$ is compatible with $g$" and "$\nabla$ is metric (w.r.t. $g$)" all just mean that $\nabla g=0$.

Comment: So what about manifolds that are not having compatible connections. Do they not have an Euler characteristic?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Given any manifold $M$ and any metric $g$ on $M$, there is always a connection compatible with $g$ on $M$ (infinitely many, in fact). Also, the CGB theorem is not a *definition* of the Euler characteristic; $\chi$ is usually [defined using various topological quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Topological_definition). In particular, $\chi(M)$ well defined for any compact topological manifold $M$.

Comment: Oh, i see. A lot has been clarified with this discussion.